# check embedded Signature in an exe file with node.js

Tags: node.js, rsa, digital-signature, verify, signtool

i have signed executables with MS signtool.
Is there a way to verify the signature with node.js and the public key but withouth the MS signtool?

i want my main node.js application to download updated exe files and verify the signature but as it is on multiple clients i can't ensure that there is signtool installed.

So there must be a way to extract the signature from the exe file and verify it with crpyto or jsrsasign.
hope someone can guide me in the right direction

regards